# iOS - Change UISwitch button color and resize it

Tags: ios, uicolor, uiswitch

I would like to change a UISwitch' button color - not the background color.

I know about "tintColor" and "onTintColor", they work very well.

[image]

This is the effect I would like to achieve though.

I have managed to change the background color to the desired color, but I'm not able to change the button itself. It's always white -- can I change its color? And is it possible to make the button smaller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no native colour tint controls for `UISwitch`. You'd need to either write your own or use something like [SevenSwitch](https://github.com/bvogelzang/SevenSwitch) or [MBSwitch](https://github.com/mattlawer/MBSwitch) to get the effect you're looking for.

Personally I prefer MBSwitch as it doesn't require the use of images, and as you can see, you get a similarly colored control to what you're asking for:

[image: img]